# How to select a d3 svg path with a particular ID

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm working with d3. I create a globe of countries from a json file. The globe has svg paths, and each path has an id. I want to select a path with a particular ID. How would I do that, please?

```
handleGlobe();

$('#panel div').click(function(){

if (this.className == 'represented') {
thisID = $(this).attr('id');
focusedCountry = d3.select('path') //??? not sure how to say this
p = d3.geo.centroid(focusedCountry);
}

...

handleGlobe() {
var feature;

        var projection = d3.geo.azimuthal()
            .scale(380)
            .origin([-71.03,42.37])
            .mode("orthographic")
            .translate([380, 400]);

        var circle = d3.geo.greatCircle()
            .origin(projection.origin());

        // TODO fix d3.geo.azimuthal to be consistent with scale
        var scale = {
          orthographic: 380,
          stereographic: 380,
          gnomonic: 380,
          equidistant: 380 / Math.PI * 2,
          equalarea: 380 / Math.SQRT2
        };

        var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);

        var svg = d3.select("#globe").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", 800)
            .attr("height", 800)
            .on("mousedown", mousedown);



        d3.json("world-countries.json", function(collection) {

         feature = svg.selectAll("path")
              .data(collection.features)
              .enter().append("svg:path")
              .attr("d", clip)
              .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
              .on("mouseover", pathOver)
              .on("mouseout", pathOut)
              .on("click", click);

          feature.append("svg:title")
              .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });

          feature.each(function(){

             for (var i=0; i<unrepresented.length; i++){
                if ($(this).attr('id') == unrepresented[i]) {
                    d3.select(this).style("fill", "#ededed");
                } 

             }
             if (($(this).attr('id') == 'GRL') || ($(this).attr('id') == 'ATA')) { //Greenland and Antarctica are shapes, but not countries
                d3.select(this).style("fill", "#ededed");
             }
          });


        });

        d3.select(window)
            .on("mousemove", mousemove)
            .on("mouseup", mouseup)
            ;

        d3.select("select").on("change", function() {
          projection.mode(this.value).scale(scale[this.value]);
          refresh(750);
        });

        var m0,
            o0;

        function mousedown() {
          m0 = [d3.event.pageX, d3.event.pageY];
          o0 = projection.origin();
          d3.event.preventDefault();
        }

        function mousemove() {
          if (m0) {
            var m1 = [d3.event.pageX, d3.event.pageY],
                o1 = [o0[0] + (m0[0] - m1[0]) / 8, o0[1] + (m1[1] - m0[1]) / 8];
            projection.origin(o1);
            circle.origin(o1)
            refresh();
          }
        }

        function mouseup() {
          if (m0) {
            mousemove();
            m0 = null;
          }
        }

        function refresh(duration) {
          (duration ? feature.transition().duration(duration) : feature).attr("d", clip);
        }

        function clip(d) {
          return path(circle.clip(d));
        }

        function click() {

        }

        function pathOver() {

        }

        function pathOut() {

        }
    //end globe

}
```

Comment: `d3.select("#<id of path>")`

Comment: Actually, I have two elements with this id. One is just a div, the other is in #globe svg path. How do I indicate the path?

Comment: focusedCountry = d3.select('#globe svg path #' + thisID);

Comment: If the other one is a `div`, you can use `d3.select("path#ID")`. Does that solve it for you? Oh and you really shouldn't have two elements with the same ID.

Comment: My next line of code is  

p = d3.geo.centroid(focusedCountry); and when I put that in, I get the message TypeError: d3.geo.centroid is not a function.

Comment: You would need to call the method to get the centroid with the underlying data (i.e. the feature), not the SVG path. Are you ok to select the path by ID now though?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can select an element by ID by prefixing the ID with "#" and using that as a selector:

```
d3.select("#ID");
```

or to select a path with that ID

```
d3.select("path#ID");
```

Comment: Just be careful, d3.select() does not like it if id is all numeric.

Comment: @mmatt All numeric IDs are not valid according to the DOM spec -- nothing to do with D3 as such.

Comment: Good to know, jQuery did not make it a problem so I thought it was d3 being mean :)